# struct.unpack changes program and distorts output?

Tags: python, struct, scapy

I've written a function for scapy which helps dissecting a packet. The function receives a raw packet and returns the class needed to dissect the contained data. The function should work, yet it somehow returns the wrong classes. Now I tested something. I just added the line

`struct.unpack("!B", packet)`

at the beginning of the function, which actually does nothing, but - and that's what's strange to me - somehow this makes the function do what it's supposed to. How can this be? I've tested it multiple times. Without this one line at the beginning of the function it does not work properly, with this line, however, it behaves like it should, although the output seems a bit distorted and I don't know why either.

Output with the line. It's distorted, some lines are at the wrong place and some are even duplicated.

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  src       = 00:30:de:09:c7:76
  dst       = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  type      = 0x800
  src       = 00:30:de:09:c7:83
###[ IP ]###
  type      = 0x800     version   = 4L

     ihl       = 5L
###[ IP ]###
     tos       = 0x0
     version   = 4L
     len       = 52
     ihl       = 5L
     id        = 312
     tos       = 0x0     flags     = DF

     frag      = 0L
     len       = 52
     ttl       = 64
     id        = 91
     proto     = udp
     flags     = DF
     frag      = 0L
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = 0xb52d
     chksum    = 0xb60b
     src       = 192.168.1.4
     src       = 192.168.1.3
     dst       = 192.168.1.255     dst       = 192.168.1.255

     \options   \
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
###[ UDP ]###        sport     = 47808

        dport     = 47808
        sport     = 47808
        len       = 32
        dport     = 47808
        chksum    = 0x6cec
        len       = 32
###[ BVLC ]###
        chksum    = 0x79eb
           type      = 0x81
###[ BVLC ]###
           function  = ORIGINAL_BROADCAST_NPDU
           type      = 0x81
           length    = 24
           function  = ORIGINAL_BROADCAST_NPDU###[ NPDU ]###

              version   = 1
           length    = 24
              control   = 32L
###[ NPDU ]###
              dnet      = 65535
              version   = 1
              dlen      = 0              control   = 32L

              hopCount  = 255
              dnet      = 65535
###[ APDU ]###
              dlen      = 0
                 pduType   = UNCONFIRMED_SERVICE_REQUEST
              hopCount  = 255
                 reserved  = None
###[ APDU ]###
                 serviceChoice= I_AM
                 pduType   = UNCONFIRMED_SERVICE_REQUEST
                 \tagsField \
                 reserved  = None
                  |###[ Raw ]###
                 serviceChoice= I_AM
                  |  load      = '\xc4\x02\t\xc7\x83"\x01\xe0\x91\x00!\xde'
                 \tagsField \
                  |###[ Raw ]###
                  |  load      = '\xc4\x02\t\xc7v"\x01\xe0\x91\x00!\xde'
```

Without the line the output looks like this, but the data is actually wrong. The Raw layer should actually be an APDU layer.

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src       = 00:30:de:09:c7:83
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4L
     ihl       = 5L
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 52
     id        = 105
     flags     = DF
     frag      = 0L
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = 0xb5fd
     src       = 192.168.1.3
     dst       = 192.168.1.255
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
        sport     = 47808
        dport     = 47808
        len       = 32
        chksum    = 0x6cec
###[ BVLC ]###
           type      = 0x81
           function  = ORIGINAL_BROADCAST_NPDU
           length    = 24
###[ NPDU ]###
              version   = 1
              control   = 32L
              dnet      = 65535
              dlen      = 0
              hopCount  = 255
###[ Raw ]###
                 load      = '\x10\x00\xc4\x02\t\xc7\x83"\x01\xe0\x91\x00!\xde'
```

The function looks like this

```
def guessBACnetTagClass(packet, **kargs):

    """ Returns the correct BACnetTag Class needed to dissect
        the current tag

        @type    packet:    binary string
        @param   packet:    the current packet

        @type    cls:       class
        @return  cls:       the correct class for dissection
    """

    struct.unpack("!B", packet) # <------ with this line it works

    # Convert main tag Byte to binary format
    tagByteBinary = "{0:08b}".format(int(struct.unpack("!B", packet[0])[0]))

    # Extract information from main tag Byte
    tagNumber = int(tagByteBinary[0:4], 2)
    tagClass = BACnetTagClass.revDict()[int(tagByteBinary[4:5], 2)]
    lengthValueType = int(tagByteBinary[5:8], 2)

    # Tag is Application Tag
    if tagClass == BACnetTagClass.APPLICATION:
        clsName = BACnetApplicationTagClasses[tagNumber]
        cls = globals()[clsName]
        print cls
        return cls(packet, **kargs)

    # Tag is Context Specific Tag
    if tagClass == BACnetTagClass.CONTEXT_SPECIFIC:
        if lengthValueType == BACnetConstructedLVT.OPENING_TAG:
            cls = BACnetTag_Opening
        if lengthValueType == BACnetConstructedLVT.CLOSING_TAG:
            cls = BACnetTag_Closing

        # Check if a class was selected
        if cls is not None:
            print cls
            return cls(packet, **kargs)
```

Does this make any sense? How can executing this one function change output this much?

Comment: Could you give an example we could reproduce? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's quite a lot of code and the project consists of several files. So I'm afraid I won't be able to give you a working example.

Comment: Wow this code is pretty magic. It would've been easier to create sublayers and properly bind them to other layers leaving all the decission making magic up to scapy. Your code is just working around this an the prints and global class guessing magic is f**** up your output - which i suspect is totally unrelated to the unpack.

Comment: In what way is that code magic? For what would you create more sublayers? I am already using three sublayers for the protocol and the third sublayer (APDU) contains a PacketListField which can contain various layers for the different Tags.